# Click an annotation twice and perform an action on the second click

Tags: ios, xcode5, mkmapview

I have a map view and I have plotted the coordinates from a JSON response.  It shows the pin/annotation name when they first click it.  Now I need to somehow allow the user to click on the same pin/annotation again and perform a seque and some action/code.  How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe you could create a tap recognizer and assign it to the annotation view when it's tapped, remove it when it's unselected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I've implemented this in many apps... First I create my own custom annotation that includes some values I might want to store that are unique to the each object associated with the pin. In this case it is a URL. Here is a generic "CustomAnnotation" object's .h and .m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface CustomAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *URL;


@end

// the .m file doesn't need anything else in it

#import "CustomAnnotation.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@implementation CustomAnnotation

@end
```

Then inside the view controller I'm adding the mapview to you need to add the annotation, customize the view that it shows when you tap it, and handle the action:

```
- (void)createMapAndAddAnnotation {
    // create the mapview and add it to the view
    MKMapView *mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    mapView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];

    // create the annotation however you want, this is just for demo purposes
    CustomAnnotation *annotation = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(50, 50);
    annotation.title = @"Test Title";
    annotation.subtitle = @"Subtitle";
    annotation.URL = @"www.google.com";
    [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    // if the annotation is a custom annotation
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotation class]]) {
        // create the reuse identifier so we can recycle annotatinons
        NSString *pinAnnotationViewReuseID = @"PinAnnotationView";

        // attempt to reuse one
        MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:pinAnnotationViewReuseID];

        // if we were unable to dequeue one for reuse
        if (!pinView) {
            // create and format it accordingly
            pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:pinAnnotationViewReuseID];
            pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
            pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
            pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        }

        // otherwise all we want to do is set the annotation on the pin
        else {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        // and return it
        return pinView;
    }

    // otherwise we don't want to return one at all
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
    // get the annotation object from the view that was tapped
    CustomAnnotation *tappedAnnotation = view.annotation;

    // get the info from the annotation itself
    NSString *urlFromAnnotation = tappedAnnotation.URL;

    // do something with the info - in this case I'm just popping up an alert for demo purposes
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"The URL was:" message:urlFromAnnotation delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}
```

Here's a video showing the result:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rbcpvo3cuspgly9/annotation.mov

EDIT: based on your edit/questions

You said you added the custom annotation files, but in the code you showed you didn't use a custom annotation object, you just used a regular MKPointAnnotation... Below I edited your code a bit to make it more readable and clear - you probably want to try making your variable names and dictionary keys make a bit more sense. This is all assuming you have an array called employees that is filled with dictionaries and each dictionary has a key called "GymName" and the value for that key is a % separated string with lat and lon values?

```
for (int index = 0; index < employees.count; index++) {
        NSLog(@"Inside Loop!");

        // get the employee dictionary based on the array index
        NSDictionary *employee = employees[index];

        // get the coordinate string - I'm guessing based on your code it's something like "45.254%72.156"
        NSString *coordinateString = employee[@"GymName"];

        // break up the lat and lon into components in an array
        NSArray *coordinateComponents = [coordinateString componentsSeparatedByString:@"%"];

        // get the latitude and longitude values from the components array and conver them to doubles
        double latitude = [coordinateComponents[0] doubleValue];
        double longitude = [coordinateComponents[1] doubleValue];

        // create the coordinate object from the lat and long
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

        // create the custom annotation and add it to the map
        CustomAnnotation *annotation = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] init];
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate;
        [_mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    }
```

Comment: I figured it out.  Thanks!  You can mark this is Answered!

Comment: Actually, you're the one that needs to mark it as answered :) Glad to help.

Comment: One quick question: I don't need to use a custom annotation right?  I can just set the rightCalloutAccessoryView and use calloutAccessoryControlTapped, correct?